# How to get values on a parent trait to be displayed in the child case class when marshalling to json?

Tags: scala, play-json

I'm having some trouble getting items in a parent trait from being recognized by child case classes when I marshall to json.

I want to create a bunch of individual children that inherit from a common parent. Like this:

```
trait Parent

case class ChildA(field1: Int) extends Parent

case class ChildB(field1: Int, field2: Int) extends Parent
```

`Parent` has some common fields:

```
trait Parent {

  val parentValue: BigDecimal = ???  // This value may be obtained through a database call

  val adjusted = {
    if (parentValue > 5) { parentValue * 0.12 }
    else { parentValue }
  }
}
```

When I marshall to Json I define a custom jswriter:

```
case class ChildA(field1: Int)

// companion obj
object ChildA {

  implicit val jsWriter = new Writes[ChildA] {
    def writes(model: ChildA): Jsvalue = {
      Json.obj(
        "parent" -> model.parentValue,
        "child-type" -> model.getClass.getSimpleName,
        "child-field-1" -> model.field1,  // for ChildB, there would need to be a child-field-2
        "adjusted" -> model.adjusted
      )
    }
}
```

(Side question, but how do I get the Children to inherit the Parent's json writer so that I can write a JsWriter for the Parent and just add the Child fields without having to write a custom marshaller for every child?)

I can marshall this to json like this:

```
val a = ChildA(6)

Json.toJson[ChildA](a)
```

But ultimately, I'd like to create a generic output so that I can do something like this:

```
val a = ChildA(6)
val b = ChildB(6, 7)
Json.toJson[Parent](a) // json of ChildA
Json.toJson[Parent](b) // json of ChildB
```

I feel that this is an opportunity to use higher-kinded or generic types. Can anyone show me how that might be done?

Comment: What would be the goal of serialization such constantes or derived values?

Comment: @cchantep Fair enough. I will fill it out with more dynamic values.

Answer (score 0):

But you did not inherit ChildA and B from Parent.
`case class ChildA(field1: Int) extends Parent`

Comment: Right. That was a typo. Question still stands.